# Handle concurrent events in Java

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

I'm having a problem with my Java code. 
I need to execute my doSomething() method, which includes code that manage also global variables. The problem is that the method is invoked twice (both mouseEvent and focusEvent of my JTable are fired at the same time). 
How can I execute the doSomething() method only once at a time, in a sort of mutual exclusion ?

Thanks.

```
addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           doSomething();
    }
});

addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){ 
           doSomething();
     }
});
```

JTable cells contains String with length 1 or 2.
I need to apply a setValue method (or delete the String), in the exact moment the user stops the cell editing or he writes a 2 character String.
With those listeners I know the exact time to do the setValue or to inform the user that the first character he wrote doesn't exist. So in that way I wanted to block the user's action.

In other words, I need to control the user input in order to do a setValue or delete it. FocusLost tells me when the user clicks outside the JTable Component.
MouseClicked tells me when the user clicks in the JTable Component.

When mouseClicked is invoked and the JOptionPane appears, the cell automatically lose the focus, and so also the focusLost is invoked.

```
public void doSomething () {
    // inEdit and tableCellEdited are the global variables
    if ( inEdit && tableCellEdited != null ) {
         String temp = "" + tableCellEdited.getDay();
         String s = tableCellEdited.getValRenderer().trim();
         if (s.length() > 2) s = s.substring(4);
         if ( !s.trim().isEmpty() ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),
                      "Code doesn't exist" , "Error: Code doesn't exist",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
              tableCellEdited.setRendererValue(getUltimaGG(), false);
          }
          else {
              tableCellEdited.setRendererValue(s, false);
              setValueAt(tableCellEdited, getRowFromMat(tableCellEdited.getMat()), Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(6, 8)) );
          }
          clearProgrammazioneDueCaratteri();
      }
  }
  repaint();
  }
```

Comment: Simplest -- don't invoke it twice. What does `doSomething()` do? Why is it being called both from a focus listener and a mouse listener?

Comment: I have to wonder if we're dealing with an XY Problem type issue, and we need to find out what overall behavior you're trying to elicit as you may want to change your approach completely.

Comment: My JTable cells contains Objects that can be made of one or two characters (Strings with lenght=1 or with lenght=2). So, I need to apply a setValueAt method when the user write the first character and then clicks outside the cell or when he goes outside the JTable Component before writing the second one... That's why I added a focusListener and a mouseListener...

Comment: Andy, thanks for that information -- could you elaborate on that and tell us more details on this exact problem? Also, put the information in as an edit to your question since it's much too important to be buried down here in comments. Again thanks.